# dynamic div is not displayed

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a simple code to display dynamic div (rewritten from a tutorial), modified it to make div an img-wrapper. But no picture is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

div1.php:

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#outerdiv').append(
    $('<div>').prop({
    id: 'myDiv',
    //innerHTML: 'Hi there!',
    className: 'img-wrapper'
    })
    );
});

$(this).css('height',"100px");

var get_a_image = "http://iancaple.ru/upload/images/20200804_225812.jpg";
    
$('#myDiv').append($('<img id="theImg2">').attr({
    'src': get_a_image , //'https://' + imgUrl ,
    'alt': 'test image '
    })
    ).scrollTop(9999)
</script>
    
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#outerdiv').append(
    $('<div>').prop({
      id: 'myDiv',
      innerHTML: 'Hi there!',
      className: 'img-wrapper',
    })
  );
});

$(this).css('height', "100px");

var get_a_image = "http://iancaple.ru/upload/images/20200804_225812.jpg";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDiv').append(
    $('<img>').prop({
      id: 'myDiv',
      'src': get_a_image, //'https://' + imgUrl ,
      'alt': 'test image ',
      'width': 200
    })
  );
});
```

```html
<div id="outerdiv"></div>
```

First insert the HTML div with ID outerdiv, then alter the js code by using the document.ready function

Comment: I did as you said. Now it shows the picture, but:
1) the image is displayed full size, not in img-wrapper
And the most important:
2) i need to have image in dynamically created myDiv, not the unique outerdiv. (I need to display several images in a loop)

Ps i also added css to display the img-wrapper

Comment: Css: .img-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
    resize: both;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:auto;
    }
    
    .img-wrapper > img {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        /*top: -50%;*/
 vertical-align: top;
    }

Comment: You can use the width attribute of the HTML element like I did, No the image is in the div with class img-wrapper, In your CSS you have also to specify the width in the .img-wrapper like width: 400px and no need for overflow I think

Comment: Now there is a new problem. As I said i need to display images in a loop. But i need to display some info between them. For example links to images and user info (html table). Now as i placed outerdiv in the beginning of my code, all the images are displayed on top of my page. But I need them spreaded throughout the page

Comment: You can style the .img-wrapper with display:block  so the images will flow vertically and you can put some space above each image by using .img-wrapper img { margin-top:30px }

Comment: I edited my comment when you answered. I said that I have html table with some of the rows containing an image, so margin won't work

Comment: Sorry I can't get your problem, If you are using tables then styling the td,tr with padding:20px will be very good

Comment: My images are displayed vertically one-by-one on top of the page. But I need them in that place in my code where I've written the script that adds new myDiv. I.e. myDiv1, myDiv2, etc.